# [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLDriverConnect in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have following configurations
from file /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora

```
**LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ol7-19.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
ODBC_CONNECTION_ORCL=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ol7-19.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ODBC_CONNECTION_ORCL)
    )
  )**
```

in file /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora

```
**ODBC_CONNECTION_ORCL=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =ol7-19.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = ODBC_CONNECTION_ORCL)
    )
  )**
```

in file /etc/odbc.ini

```
**[ODBC_CONNECTION_ORCL]
Description = ODBC CONNECTION CREATED FOR BACKUP DATABASE
Driver      = /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/lib/libsqora.so.19.1
ServerName  = //192.168.103.145:1521/ORCL
Database = ORCL
UserID = SYSTEM
Password = Test123$**
```

in file /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
**[ODBC_CONNECTION_ORCL]
Description = ODBC CONNECTION CREATED FOR BACKUP DATABASE
Driver      = /u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/lib/libsqora.so.19.1
ServerName  = //192.168.103.145:1521/ORCL
Database = ORCL
UserID = SYSTEM
Password = Test123$**
```

but still i am getting below error while trying to connect from root user but via oracle user it connected successfully..

```
**isql -k -v Driver={ODBC_CONNECTION_ORCL};DSN=ODBC_CONNECTION_ORCL;Uid=SYSTEM;Pwd=Test123$;**

**[08004][unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLDriverConnect**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check difference in environment variables, probably your `root` user can't find `tnsnames.ora` and `sqlnet.ora` files. But `oracle` user properly configured (environment variables), thus it can connect successfully. Try to execute `env` and filter output for `ORACLE_HOME`, `ORACLE_SID`, `TNS_ADMIN` and `PATH` environments variables. Compare them and align for `root` user.

And just curious - why in your showed contents of all configuration files (like `listener.ora`, `tnsnames.ora`, `odbc.ini` etc.) used two star symbols `"**"`? And also use of `root` account for any purpose except administration is not a good idea.

Comment: I want to execute rman backup script using batch script from root user and to get the status of my backup command i want to query oracle database so i need to connect from root user to oracle database via odbc .

Comment: Output of the env command 
[root@ol7-19 admin]# env | grep ORACLE
ORACLE_UNQNAME=ORCL
ORACLE_SID=ORCL
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=ol7-19.localdomain
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1
[root@ol7-19 admin]# su oracle
[oracle@ol7-19 admin]$ env | grep ORACLE
ORACLE_UNQNAME=ORCL
ORACLE_SID=ORCL
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=ol7-19.localdomain
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1

Comment: Environment variables looks similar between accounts. Anyway, error `ORA-12154` is most common and absolutely clear - it means that during attempt to establish connection was not found description of `ODBC_CONNECTION_ORCL` alias (in `tnsnames.ora` file, or file itself).

Comment: As a workaround, in order not to waste time for investigation and troubleshooting, you can just modify your backup script - it should perform backup actions as before (as root), but part performing check via connection to Oracle database should be executed as oracle user, i.e. you have to add `su oracle` call, perform necessary steps, and then call `exit`, all within same script file